# Can I hide my node js server, from outerworld with docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I have an app written with React and node js. Can I make the API invisible for users?

Comment: Short answer is 'yes'. Please describe what you are after more precisely

Comment: If you don't run it with a `-p` option, it won't be accessible from off-host.  That also means your React app running outside Docker in your browser won't be able to reach your API.

Comment: Can I run React app inside Docker, for example with nginx server?

Comment: you can add nginx server. it would function as api gateway and would hide private apis, however it's better to run nginx server as a separate container from the app

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. Can you give some links how to do it